# Can ArcREST be used with a local ArcGIS Server?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcrest

I'm looking at using ArcREST to insert rows in a featureservice on a local ArcGIS Server.

All the sample that I've seen seem to be connecting to a ArcGIS Online.

If I look at the Documentation for the [Security Handler Helper module](http://esri.github.io/ArcREST/arcresthelper.html?highlight=security#module-arcresthelper.securityhandlerhelper),
I can't see where to specify the url of the local server.

Is there a Sample for inserting rows in the featureservice of a local ArcGIS Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample you could use. I use ArcREST for most of my AGS administration workflows, it's very powerful and imho simple to use.

You will need an AGS feature service and user credentials to create a token.

```
from arcrest.manageags._services import AGSService
from arcrest.ags.server import Server
from arcrest import AGSTokenSecurityHandler
from arcrest.common.general import Feature

ags_admin_url = r"http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin"
ags_securityHandler = AGSTokenSecurityHandler(username='user', password='pwd',
                                              org_url=ags_admin_url)

base_url =  r"http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/"
ags_featureservice_service_folder = "MultiuserGdb"
ags_featureservice_name = "FS_Roads"

ags_user_mapservice_with_fs_service_url = base_url + "{0}/{1}/MapServer".format(ags_featureservice_service_folder,
                                                                                ags_featureservice_name)

ags_user_featureservice_service_url = base_url + "{0}/{1}/FeatureServer".format(ags_featureservice_service_folder,
                                                                                ags_featureservice_name)

rest_server = Server(ags_user_mapservice_with_fs_service_url,
                     ags_securityHandler)

rest_server.currentFolder = ags_featureservice_service_folder
ags_services = rest_server.services

feature_service = [service for service in ags_services
                   if service.url == ags_user_featureservice_service_url][0]

fs_layer = feature_service.layers[0]

features_to_add_to_feature_service = r"C:\GIS\GitProjects\unit_tests_arcrest\GeoData\FeatureServiceInData.gdb\feats_to_add"

features = Feature.fc_to_features(features_to_add_to_feature_service)
result = fs_layer.addFeature(features)
print result
```

The printed info:

```
{u'addResults': [{u'success': True, u'objectId': 7514}, {u'success': True, u'objectId': 7515}, {u'success': True, u'objectId': 7516}, {u'success': True, u'objectId': 7517}]}
```